# Aerospike: lua udf always returns an empty result even if udf return stream without any filtering, etc

Tags: lua, udf, aerospike

Can not understand why aggregateQuery always returns an empty result. Tried to test in aql, the same problem: 0 rows in set.

Indexes are all there.

```
aql> show indexes
+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| ns            | bin         | indextype | set        | state | indexname                    | path        | sync_state | type      |
+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| "test"        | "name"      | "NONE"    | "profiles" | "RW"  | "inx_test_name"              | "name"      | "synced"   | "STRING"  |
| "test"        | "age"       | "NONE"    | "profiles" | "RW"  | "inx_test_age"               | "age"       | "synced"   | "NUMERIC" |


aql> select * from test.profiles
+---------+-----+
| name    | age |
+---------+-----+
| "Sally" | 19  |
| 20      |     |
| 22      |     |
| 28      |     |
| "Ann"   | 22  |
| "Bob"   | 22  |
| "Tammy" | 22  |
| "Ricky" | 20  |
| 22      |     |
| 19      |     |
+---------+-----+
10 rows in set (0.026 secs)


aql>  AGGREGATE mystream.avg_age() ON test.profiles WHERE age BETWEEN 20 and 29
0 rows in set (0.004 secs)
```

Comment: Can you share the lua file and the query result via aql for the same with without udf invocation.

Comment: Do you have an index built on the _age_ bin? What happens when you just `SELECT * FROM test.profiles WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 29`? Also, you need to show your Lua module to have this figured out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying the example [here](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/querying_records.html#aggregating-on-query-or-scan-results).
There are two problems about the udf script. I paste the code of the lua script :

```
function avg_age(stream)

  local function female(rec)
    return rec.gender == "F"
  end

  local function name_age(rec)
    return map{ name=rec.name, age=rec.age }
  end

  local function eldest(p1, p2)
    if p1.age > p2.age then 
      return p1
    else
      return p2
    end
  end

  return stream : filter(female) : map(name_age) : reduce(eldest)
end
```

**First, there is no bin named 'gender' in your set, so you got 0 rows after aggregateQuery.**
Second, this script isn't doing exactly what the function name 'avg_age' means, it just return the eldest record with name and age.

I paste my code bellow, it just replace the reduce func, and alert the map and filter func to meat the demand. You can just skip the filter process.

```
function avg_age(stream)
  count = 0
  sum = 0

  local function female(rec)
    return true
  end

  local function name_age(rec)
    return rec.age
  end

  local function avg(p1, p2)
    count = count + 1
    sum = sum + p2
    return sum / count
  end

  return stream : filter(female) : map(name_age) : reduce(avg)
end
```

The output looks like bellow :

```
AGGREGATE mystream.avg_age() ON test.avgage WHERE age BETWEEN 20 and 29
+---------+
| avg_age |
+---------+
| 22      |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 secs)
```